# AWS Cognito - Confirmation Code not received

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I created an user pool with AWS Cognito. It works good but many email servers (providers like FreeTelecom our Orange in France) never received the Confirmation Code (in order to validate an email address and activate a user account). I found nothing in the AWS Documentation. Please someone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Image url: [image]

Please do find the image url and open it for reference.
While creating your user pool you have to enable MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) on aws console.
Do verify 1. whether you have Marked MFA as ***required*** field. 2.Which second factors do you want to enable? Enable an option ***OTP or SMS*** 3.Do you want to require verification of emails or phone numbers? Check the field both ***Email and Phone Number***